# Get unique elements of an abject array by merging elements with same value of field

Tags: javascript, arrays, distinct

There is an array with some objects, which could have elements with the same title (and different type). 
Those elements should be merged to get a result array with unique titles, but the info of the individual object shouldn't get lost.

So this...

```
array = [
    { id: 1, title: 'one', type: 'infos' },
    { id: 2, title: 'two', type: 'infos' },
    { id: 3, title: 'same', type: 'infos' },   // <--
    { id: 1, title: 'oneDiff', type: 'article' },
    { id: 2, title: 'same', type: 'article' },
    { id: 3, title: 'three', type: 'article' } // <--
]
```

...should get:

```
distinct = [
    { id: 1, title: 'one', type: 'infos' },
    { id: 2, title: 'two', type: 'infos' },
    { id: 1, title: 'oneDiff', type: 'article' },
    { id: 3, title: 'three', type: 'article' },
    { id: [{ id: 3, type: 'infos'}, { id: 2, type: 'article'}], title: 'same', type: 'multiple' }
]
```

I tried to start with this, but I failed to get the result I need:

```
var unique = {};
var distinct = [];
for( var i in array ){
    if( typeof(unique[array[i].title]) == "undefined"){
        distinct.push(array[i].title);
    }
    unique[array[i].title] = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to do it with array.reduce. So if you don't support ie8 you can use it. One note: I couldn't do it without extra array.

```
var tempArray = [];
var result = array.reduce(function (memo, element) {
    var index = tempArray.indexOf(element.title);

    if (index === -1) {
        tempArray.push(element.title);
        memo.push(element);
    } else {
        if (typeof memo[index].id === 'number') {
            memo[index].id = [{
                id: memo[index].id,
                type: memo[index].type
            }];

            memo[index].type = 'multiple';
        }

        memo[index].id.push({
            id: element.id,
            type: element.type
        });

        tempArray.push(null);
    }

    return memo;
}, []);
```

[Example on jsbin](http://jsbin.com/lolose/edit?js,console)

Comment: What do I have to change, if I'm using string IDs like `id: 'n4s55Xqtb8NxPSzx5'`?

Comment: in this condition "if (typeof memo[index].id === 'number') {" you can change type "number" to "string"

Comment: Hmm.. This didn't work work for me. Don't understand why. I try to find out why...

Answer (score 0):

I have a quick idea. 
Why don't you concat the title and the type together, and put them together in a single array?
So if you had

```
title: 'apple'
type: 'golden'
```

then you would concat them together with an underscore to get

```
apple_golden
```

Of course, this would only work if you didn't have underscores in any of the titles or types. If you did, you could make a unique combination of characters that symbolized the start of a new word.

For instance:

```
apple!-!-!golden
```